# Shell script run in telnet well, but not via cron

Tags: shell, cron, sh

I just started to learn shells scripting.

Trying to run script in cron, without success. In telnet when i run "sh.script.sh" output is as expected. What I miss?

script.sh is in /usr/bin folder.

```
#!/bin/sh

var1 = $(opkg update)
echo ${var1}
```

Comment: welcome to SO.  it is unclear what you are trying to do with cron and odd that you are using telnet.  can you give us a clearer description of what is not working?

Comment: Assigning the output to a variable then echo'ing the variable is redundant. You just need `opkg update` in your script. Additionally, you need to make your script executable with `chmod +x /usr/bin/script.sh` -
 the way you are testing is different than how cron with run it (please at your crontab line to question). Finally, I would recommend putting the full path to "opkg" in the script because when cron runs things it does not have the same environment variables, such as $PATH, set and cron may not be able to find "opkg."

Answer (score 0):

try simply this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

var1=$(opkg update)
echo $var1
```